# PHP DOMPDF html to PDF converter font rendering issue in v.0.6.1

Tags: php, unicode, fonts, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF v.0.6.1 downloaded from [github](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) to  convert HTML to PDF file. I am facing fontdisplay issue with while adding my custom font in configuration. dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php

I used http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/load_font.php to generate Unicode TAMIL font(latha by microsoft font) .I have copied the fonts into respective folders.

But I see the fonts are not printing  as it is.

**My code:**

```
<p style="font-family: tamil-latha, verdana, sans-serif;" >தமிழ்</p>
```

**But what is printed in PDF is :**

[image]

Both the values are not Same. There is some box is coming near the font and a dot on last character is missing..

Note: I have also added newly created font into **dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php**

```
    'tamil-latha' => 
  array (
    'normal' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'latha',
    'bold' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'latha',
    'italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'latha',
    'bold_italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'latha',
  ),
```

I have raised the same question in github here : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/838

**Suggested Solution was:**  use dompdf **v.0.6.2** But there is no such version available here : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
Help me if you are able to get v.0.6.2

Comment: I also can't see a 0.6.2 tag. Have you tried the Dev branch?
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/develop

Comment: @DaryllDoyle : yes, I had already tried with but no use... Do you suggest any other API for PDF generation which can work for all fonts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dompdf](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/) appears to have issues with UTF-8 encoding. I tried your sample with dompdf and I ran into the same issue you did. However, I also tried it with [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) (also free) it appears to work well.

[image]

Here is the code for your sample, and the full source [can be downloaded here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32522547/tcpdf.zip).

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;//chrome
require_once('tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 12);

$pdf->AddPage();

$utf8text = '
<html><head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head><body>
<p>தமிழ்</p>
</body></html>';

$pdf->writeHTML($utf8text, true, 0, true, true);

$pdf->Output('example_008.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

Comment: Thank you much Josh. Much appreciated :) 
I will try in my pc and let you . Does it require any installation ? or  just copy pasting the files will work ? Also let me know will it work for combination of English & Tamil font display at same time. (currently dont have pc to test. Please let me know)

Comment: @logan you just need to copy the files into your web server directory. I didn't need to use Tamil font--the default font worked just fine (so yes, English and Tamil should work together). The key thing to remember is the encoding needs to be UTF-8 (and you need a pdf library to support that).

Comment: Thanks :) . PDF library, you meant is tcpdf supported files right ? or any other files ?

Comment: @logan right, tcpdf-supported files. I put a link to a zip of my complete code, including the library. Try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: You are great ! I just tested it. It worked fine :) Thanks for solving my problem. 50 bounties for you :)

Comment: example shown just popups as downloadable file. Could you please let me know how to save output it unix directory ?

Comment: @logan glad it worked out! :) I look forward to receiving the bounty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56557/discussion-between-logan-and-josh).

Comment: how is your web server configured? you need to extract the zip contents and place them in your webserver root.

Comment: I have asked for the output `example_008.pdf` . It just comes as downloadable file. i need to save `example_008.pdf` in to unix directory ?

Comment: Again , problem with 2nd word. When i tried to print `    தமிழ்   முந்திரி` words, 2nd word was not printed properly. Please my own answer added to this post.

Comment: Thanks. Also please let me know if I can set my own fonts for printing UTF-8

Comment: Did you get a chance to see ?

Comment: The blanket statement that dompdf has trouble with UTF-8 encoding isn't entirely correct. Internationalization support isn't perfect, but the sample text renders fine with v0.6.1 and a supporting font.

Comment: @logan I couldn't get past the issue either. Did you try with the Latha font in CSS3?

Comment: @josh : I tried mpdf , the issue is not coming now. and the rendering is also better than tcpdf. Do you see any disadvantages with mpdf expect time?

Comment: @logan I've never used mpdf but it looks very promising; I don't see any disadvantages.

Comment: @logan Same issue is continuing for me in TCPDF and MPDF. Can you share your settings or any suggestions?

Comment: The same issues for Kannada fonts also. Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with tcpdf as suggested by josh.
Now the previous word is coming fine but new word is not displayed properly.

```
$utf8text = '
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>     <body><p>தமிழ்      முந்திரி </p></body>        </html>';
```

Actual Answer in PDF is :

[image]

Comment: Not a native speaker, so pardon the question, is that a single character or two characters that combine into a single letter? Right now I doubt there are many PHP-based libraries that can handle compound letters. I see the same issue in dompdf. Either that or the font you're using doesn't have a good glyph for the character in question.