# Tamil font rendering issue in TCPDF

Tags: php, utf-8, tcpdf

We have developed a Tamil text PDF generation using TCPDF (https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf), we used the following tamil fonts

1. tamilavarangal.z,tamilavarangal.php
2. akshar.z,akshar.php
3. tau.z,tau.php
4. vaigai.z,vaigai.php
5. tscu.z,tscu.php

But the tamil text in PDF Generated as below

[image]

We followed the below process also, [PHP DOMPDF html to PDF converter font rendering issue in v.0.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440261/php-dompdf-html-to-pdf-converter-font-rendering-issue-in-v-0-6-1/24483450#24483450)

Eventhough the Tamil Text is not rendering properly.

Kindly let us know your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mpdf version 8.2.0